# Quiz timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, web, timer

i am building a quiz in javascript and i want to set the a timer for each question and yet  i cant seem to achieve it. Here is my code:

````
 function start(){
    let correct = 0;
    let incorrect = 0;
    let question = "none";
    let input = "none";
    let answer = "none";
//  the ask function
let ask = function(){
    input = prompt(question); 
};
// the score function 
let score = function(){
    if(input==answer){ // if (condition){ do smtin} else { do smtin}
       correct = correct+1;
       alert("Correct");
 } else{
     incorrect= incorrect+1;
     alert("Incorrect");
 }
};
//  this function calls both the ask and score functions
let both = function(){
    ask();
    score();
};```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var timeLeft = 30; // In seconds
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        // doSomething();
    } else {
        console.log(timeLeft + ' seconds remaining');
        timeLeft--;
    }
}
```

call countdown to start the timer and change the duration in timeLeft variable
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried your code above, but instead of timing the questions, it acts as a countdown after a question is answered. I mean the number of seconds only reduces after a question is answered. Any help?

Comment: Can I have a look at your implementation of the code. Like to the snippet of your code where you are calling the above function?